# Does someone have a good solution for java with Chrome browser?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, java

Similiar questions are everywhere, but I haven't found anyone that actually has a good solution.

Previously I have been able to choose "Run java this time" and avoid upgrading to the always latest very important security update. I try to avoid this because I ALWAYS get problems with the installation.

Now, I was stupid enough to do this in my Chrome web browser, leading to yet again a failure in loading java applets on web.

Does anyone have a good solution to making it work? Now I am stuck with endless messages that tells me to upgrade my already upgraded java version. I am using x64 Windows 7 (and yes, I download the x64 version)

Comment: is your `$PATH` variable pointing to x64 Java? that might be the issue, if you have 32bit and 64bit Java installed.

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7` to path, didn't work :\ +1 for nick ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that Chrome on Windows is 32bits, you need the 32bit version of java to have the plugin load in Chrome.

Comment: didn't work with either of the versions

Comment: @Wilhelmsen - What do you mean it didn't work.  I am pretty sure Chrome comes with Java extension by default.

Comment: Yes @Ramhound, but when installing an update with the chrome plugin everything stops working. By "it didn't work", I mean that java applets dont work, and chrome asks me to install an update, again, and again, and again... you get it

Comment: @Wilhelmsen - Have you tried to use `Java Ra` to clean your Java installation?  http://singularlabs.com/software/javara/

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound! In collaboration with this answer and your removal method it worked. user2313067, that was the problem at hand, but I hadn't been able to remove java properly before installation of the 32 bit version